# Validar un campo tagsinput de emails con jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-tags-input

Tengo un campo con el que el usuario añade varias direcciones de correo electrónico y se van guardando en tags. El plugin que uso para esto es el tagsinput de bootstrap. 
Sería necesario que validara cada tag como email. El html del campo es el siguiente:

```
<input class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" id="email" placeholder="Introduce una dirección email válida" name="email" type="text" style="display: none;">
```

Cuando guardo este campo en la base de datos lo que devuelve es algo similar a lo siguiente: email1@test.com,email2@test.com, ...

Y lo que monta en html es:

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
<span class="tag label label-info">mail1@test1.com <span data-role="remove"></span>
</span> <span class="tag label label-info">mail2@test.com <span data-role="remove"></span>
</span> <span class="tag label label-info">mail3@test.com <span data-role="remove"></span></span> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce una dirección email válida" size="36">
```

[image: Renderizado en html del plugin]

Es decir lo que me interesa es validar cada uno de esos span con jquery validate pero no encuentro la manera. ¿Alguna ayuda?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atendiendo al problema que presentas debes conocer de antemano que el plugin de tags que empleas oculta el verdadero campo que estas validando, por tanto tienes que tener en cuenta esto a la hora de validar ya que por defecto jquery-validate ignora los campos ocultos. Sabiendo esto puedes seguir mi ejemplo

Este es el html, no pongo las librerias porque son las mismas que empleas

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1" data-role="tagsinput"/>
        <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ahora el código javascript

```
<script>
    //Añado un nuevo método a las reglas de validación de jquery validate
    $.validator.addMethod( "tag_email", function( value, element, params ){
        //Si el elemento es opcional devuelvo true para no validarlo
        if(this.optional(element)){
          return true;
        }
        /*Como me has dicho que el valor que se almacena en la base de datos
        es de la forma correo@email.cu,correo@email.cu separo este texto por
        los delimitadores */
        var parts = value.split(',');
        //Creo esta variable para detener el ciclo siguiente cuando no es un correo válido
        var fail = false;
        //Recorro la lista de los correos
        for(var i in parts){
            /*Verifico que sea una dirección de correo correcta, es la misma
              expresión regular que usa esta librería para la regla email */
            if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(parts[i].trim()) === false){
              //Si falla la verificación pongo a true esta variable y salgo del ciclo
              fail = true;
              break;
            }
        }
        //Devuelve true si el elemento a validar es opcional o si no hay ningun fallo cuando valida los correos contenidos en su valor
        return this.optional(element) || !fail;
    //Este es el mensaje de error que voy a devolver
    }, "Existen direcciones de correo incorrectas");

  /* Con esto valido mi formulario observar que puse ignore en "" ya que
  inicialmente es ":hidden" y agregué la nueva regla tag_email */
  $('form').validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
         'campo1': {
            required: true,
            tag_email: true
         }
     }
  });

 //Omití el inicializador del tagsinput no tiene relevancia en este problema
```

Espero que funcione si necesitas algo más puedo hacerte un fiddle en caso de que no te funcione, aunque ya lo he probado. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @Daniel ha funcionado correctamente. Al ser el campo hidden no coge la clase error y no se ilumina de rojo (que es como lo tengo en css) ni tampoco detecta que hay un error al momento, solo al hacer el submit. Pero funcionar funciona. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda. Me has salvado el día. :)

Comment: Lo que tienes configurado en css eso lo haces en la configuración del validate del formulario, si es que te refieres a por ejemplo que el error sea un label que tenga una clase x y se posicione debajo del control que tiene el error.